# virtfs works in standalone QEMU, but not in Yocto-qemu

Tags: qemu, yocto-project

I need to mount a folder (or whatever) to a filesystem in qemu. mounting FAT worked in Poky, but not on our custom image. So... I tried virtfs, because it looks promising. Again I used Poky as a reference to get it working there first.

I use this command:

```
runqemu slirp nographic qemuparams="-virtfs local,path=$PWD/testfolder,security_model=none,mount_tag=host_share"
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. It throws the following error:

```
runqemu - ERROR - Failed to run qemu: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.x2apic [bit 21]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.tsc-deadline [bit 24]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.x2apic [bit 21]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.tsc-deadline [bit 24]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.x2apic [bit 21]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.tsc-deadline [bit 24]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.x2apic [bit 21]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.tsc-deadline [bit 24]
qemu-system-x86_64: -virtfs local,path=/home/myname/poky/build/testfolder,security_model=none,mount_tag=host_share: 'virtio-9p-pci' is not a valid device model name
```

From what I can tell from Google, the first messages can be ignored, and only the last line matters.

I struggled for a while with this, and tried to run the exact same command as `runqemu` generates, but instead run it in QEMU installed from the apt-repositories.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=52:54:00:12:35:02 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:2222-:22,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:2323-:23,tftp=/home/myname/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64 -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0 -drive file=/home/myname/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/core-image-minimal-qemux86-64-20230504075342.rootfs.ext4,if=virtio,format=raw -usb -device usb-tablet -usb -device usb-kbd   -cpu IvyBridge -machine q35 -smp 4 -m 256 -serial mon:stdio -serial null -nographic  -kernel /home/myname/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/bzImage -append 'root=/dev/vda rw  ip=dhcp console=ttyS0 console=ttyS1 oprofile.timer=1 tsc=reliable no_timer_check rcupdate.rcu_expedited=1 ' -virtfs local,path=$PWD/testfolder,security_model=passthrough,mount_tag=host_share
```

To my surprise, this worked! No error at bootup, and I can mount the fs without any problems afterwards. So... something must be different between the QEMU Yocto generates and the QEMU that is built by apt.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370768/qemu-virtio-9p-pci-is-not-a-valid-device-model-name) on StackOverflow where someone had the same issue. This person had compiled his QEMU himself. So, I went and dug in the logfiles of both my Yocto and the [apt buid logfiles](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/661233710/buildlog_ubuntu-focal-amd64.qemu_1%3A4.2-3ubuntu6.26_BUILDING.txt.gz).

I found that indeed, as the answer in the above linked SO Question said, virtfs was not enabled as a compile flag.
I then created a bbappend file with this content:
`PACKAGECONFIG:append = " virtfs"`

From the verbose build logs, I can now see that the `--enable-virtfs` is added to `./configure` and that `virtfs : enabled` is also shown in the overview.

Surely, it has to work now, right? Unfortunately, no... I still get the same error has I had initially...

So I'm a bit at a loss here... what else could there be wrong? I know there's a bunch more options that are different between the builds, but I have no clue which ones are relevant.

If it's useful, here's what I believe to be the relevant snippets of the [apt build](https://pastebin.com/raw/JFcGHUtx) and the [yocto build](https://pastebin.com/raw/XbvzBzAV).